# ZXing calls parent's onCreate after scanning

Tags: android, zxing, oncreate

I have a problem with ZXing activities : When a scan succeeds, it works properly, goes back to parent activity, sets the result in the textfield, but calls the onCreate method of its parent which is very problematic for me.

Here is my result listener :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (scanResult != null) {
            String ean = scanResult.getContents();
            eanEdit.setText(ean);
        }
    } else {
        // Nothing
    }
}
```

The button listener :

```
public void addScanButtonListener() {
    scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
            integrator.addExtra("SCAN_WIDTH", 800);
            integrator.addExtra("SCAN_HEIGHT", 200);
            integrator.addExtra("RESULT_DISPLAY_DURATION_MS", 0L);
            integrator.addExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "EAN_13,EAN_8");
            integrator.addExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", false);
            integrator.addExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE", "Scan please");
            integrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);
        }
    });
}
```

Would you have any clue ?

Answer (score 2):

No, Android calls `onCreate()` in your `Activity` if anything does. Android may destroy and re-create your app at any time if needed. So you need to implement `onDestroy()` and `onCreate()` appropriately to be prepared for this.

Comment: Isn't it possible to make ZXing not to destroy my application activity, just to keep it in background ? How to know that the application was already launched not to reload part of the onCreate() function ?

Comment: Apps can't affect other apps at all this way. This has nothing to do with any other app; you need to implement your app lifecycle correclty.